# Execute a flask run in Jenkins shell without timeout

Tags: python, jenkins, flask

I'm using Jenkins to run a Flask app automatically from a Git branch.
The build works well, and it starts the Flask app on my server, except that when you run `flask run`, the command line stays active as long as the flask app runs.
Thus, the build never ends, and it ends up as an unstable build.

How can I get the flask app to run and get a Jenkins build success if it got the the `* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)` message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running `flask run` in a bash script, adding `&` to the end (`flask run &`) will run the task in the background, allowing the bash script to continue. I think this will let your job finish and Jenkins can scan stdout for the message indicating success.

Edit: Apparently overriding the build number `export BUILD_ID=<whatever>` is enough to stop Jenkins from killing the background process. I'd be wary of what you choose as `<whatever>`, if you choose an existing BUILD_ID, there could be side-effects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works as in it gives me a successful Jenkins build, but it seems like the end of the build also puts an end to the flask app...and thus I can't access it via my navigator. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like Jenkins kills the backgrounded process when the job ends. Maybe you can write a simple script that launches Flask in the background and have Jenkins run the script that starts Flask. This may keep it running after Jenkins finishes the launcher script, but I'm not positive.

Comment: Ok, the solution is to add a line to the shell script, at the beginning:
export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe
(dontKillMe can be anything, of course). If you add this to your answer I will accept it !

Comment: I've added the edit. Sounds like a decent workaround, just be careful what you choose as the BUILD_ID. I'd be slightly concerned about choosing an existing BUILD_ID and effecting another build.

Comment: @mindfolded This magically works! I just wonder why that happen? It seems so weird.